# Dynamically set names based on stock symbols with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

For my stock quotes widget, I'm trying to dynamically set a name for each stock symbol (GCF14.CMX ---> Gold).

My code here: http://jsfiddle.net/thetuneupguy/JaCaH/1/

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20WHERE%20symbol%20in(%22GCF14.CMX%22%2C%22SIF14.CMX%22%2C%22PAH14.NYM%22%2C%22PLF14.NYM%22)&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=', function (data) {
    console.log("data: ", data);
    console.log(data.query.results.quote);
    $.each(data.query.results.quote, function (key, obj) {
        var obj = {};
        obj['GCF14.CMX'] = Gold;
        var changeClass = '';
        var changeInPercentClass = '';
        var $tr = $('<tr/>', {
            'class': 'my-new-list'
        }).appendTo('#blk-1 table');
        $tr.append($('<td id="name" class="cells"/>').text(obj || "--"));
        $tr.append($('<td class="cells"/>').text(obj.AskRealtime || "--"));
        //$tr.append($('<td/>').text(obj.BidRealtime || "--"));

        (obj.Change.substr(0,1) === '+') ? changeClass = 'green' : changeClass = 'red';

        (obj.Change.substr(0,1) === '+') ? changeInPercentClass = 'green' : changeInPercentClass = 'red';

        $tr.append($('<td class="'+changeClass+'">').text(obj.ChangeRealtime|| "--"));
        var re = /([+|-]\d\.\d\d\%)/gi;
        var rt = re.exec(obj.ChangePercentRealtime);
        $tr.append($('<td class="'+changeInPercentClass+'">').text( rt[0] || "--"));
     });
   });
});
```

I've been playing with...

```
var obj = {};
obj['GCF14.CMX'] = Gold;
```

along with...

```
$tr.append($('<td id="name" class="cells"/>').text(obj || "--"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a name field on the response that you are getting...

Don't do this...

```
var obj = {};
obj['GCF14.CMX'] = Gold;
```

That code takes the obj containing all your information and sets it to a blank object (breaking everything). It then attempts to set obj['GCF14.CMX'] equal to an undefined object.

All you need is

```
$tr.append($('<td id="name" class="cells"/>').text(obj.Name || "--"));
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/JaCaH/3/

Comment: I don't want those names. They are appended with date information. I just want the individual metals.

Comment: Well then you can split on spaces and take the first string in the resulting array - http://jsfiddle.net/JaCaH/4/